# Teradata SQL numeric to timestamp or date

Tags: sql, teradata, numeric, sql-timestamp

I need to change a column that looks like this =" 202007211330231166 " into time stamp or date format = 21/07/2020 & time = 1:30 pm i.e. (1330 <- part) Help. I was attempting to use Substring to capture the date & time sections.

select InfoData from dbc.dbcinfoV where InfoKey = 'RELEASE';
= version of Teradata 16.20.53.13

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, split the string and then CAST it:

```
cast(substring(col from 1 for 8) as date format 'yyyymmdd')
cast(substring(col from 9 for 4) as time(0) format 'hhmi')
```